# Reading data from firebase (ios)

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a small dataset in Firebase database, but unfortunately, I can't get read value from list correctly. Here is the structure of the database.
[image]

I just need to get the value of day and reference it to var. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please show the code that you tried so far..

Comment: var collnum = ""
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        let collid = ref.child("collid").child("day")
        collid.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot)in
        collnum = snapshot.key})
        print(collnum)

Comment: can you check the Rules defined for Database ?

Comment: "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }

Answer (score 1):

```
var collnum = "" 
ref = Database.database().reference() 
let collid = ref.child("collid").child("day") 


collid.observeSingleEvent(of : .value, with : {(Snapshot) in

        print(Snapshot)

        if let snapDate = Snapshot.value as? String{
                    collnum = snapDate
                   print(snapDate)
            }
    })
```

Comment: unfortunately, not working correctly, still can't get value in day

Comment: can you tell me what value is getting logged in  print(Snapshot) ?

Comment: it's not getting any value,printing blank line

Comment: after you edited the code,it works but printing everything in database

Comment: can you please write the debug log

Comment: what is the issue? what is the value in print(Snapshot) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
   let database = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
   database.child("collid").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.value, with: 
   { 
       if let value = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] 
       {
          let ui = value["day"] as! String
          print(ui)
       }  
   }
```

You can do something like this to read the data. This will read the data from the database and put into an array, allowing you to read the data.